# Exceptions specific for SQL Server database operations

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

When catching an exception on a database reading/writing operation, what specific exceptions should I try to catch in a Try-Catch construction?

```
try
{
   MyDatabaseHandlingMethod();             
}
catch (exception ex)//what to use instead of just "exception"?
{
    //exception handling
}
```

What are those exceptions to use instead of just "exception" in case of trying to perform a database related operation? (like `IOException` in case of file handling operations)

Comment: Are you looking for SqlException Error codes? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380547/a-list-of-common-sqlexception-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server exceptions will be of type `SqlException` - they contain an `Errors` collection that holds a list of `SqlError` objects that contain the detailed information about the exception.

For reference see MSDN:

- [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx)
- [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to handle SqlException that has `Number` property.